# Convert full-width Unicode characters into ASCII characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, ascii

I have some string text in unicode, containing some numbers as below:

```
txt = '３６fsdfdsf１４'
```

However, `int(txt[:2])` does not recognize the characters as number. How to change the characters to have them recognized as number?

Comment: works for me in 3.4. what's your python version.

Comment: your text isn't unicode because it doesn't have the `u` prefix (python 2 needs it)

Answer (score 2):

If you actually have Unicode (or decode your byte string to Unicode) then you can normalize the data with a canonical replacement:

```
>>> s = u'３６fsdfdsf１４'
>>> s
u'\uff13\uff16fsdfdsf\uff11\uff14'
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.normalize('NFKC',s)
u'36fsdfdsf14'
```

If canonical normalization changes too much for you, you can make a translation table of just the replacements you want:

```
#coding:utf8

repl = u'0123456789'

# Fullwidth digits are U+FF10 to U+FF19.
# This makes a lookup table from Unicode ordinal to the ASCII character equivalent.
xlat = dict(zip(range(0xff10,0xff1a),repl))

s = u'３６fsdfdsf１４'

print(s.translate(xlat))
```

Output:

```
36fsdfdsf14
```

Answer (score 0):

On python 3

```
[int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', '３６fsdfdsf１４')]
# [36, 14]
```

On python 2

```
[int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', u'３６fsdfdsf１４', re.U)]
# [36, 14]
```

About python 2 example, notice the 'u' in front of string and `re.U` flag.  You may convert existing `str` typed variable such as `txt` in your question to unicode as `txt.decode('utf8')`.

Comment: Yes, what python version are you running?

Comment: it works, but regex part is pointless, and it doesn't really answer the actual OP question.

Comment: I think using `re` makes it safer. If your variable type is `str` (which you may miss it completely),  `txt[0]` returns `'\xef'`, but if it is unicode same indexing returns `u'\uff13'` - for python 2.